# Valid C code doesn't work in Swift project

Tags: c, swift, macos, unix-socket

I have code:

```cpp
#define SOCK_PATH "/Users/piotr/swigo.sock"

int ux_server_socket() {
    const int fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (fd == -1) {
        printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    struct sockaddr_un addr;
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sun_len = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(addr.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);

    if (unlink(addr.sun_path) == -1) {
        printf("unlink: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    int retv = bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, (socklen_t)SUN_LEN(&addr));
    if (retv == -1) {
        printf("bind: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    printf("valid socket: %d\n", fd);
    return fd;
}
```

When I create a project in C language in Xcode, this code works without any problems (in the console appears: valid socket: 3). However, when I create a project in Swift (Cocoa App), I added a C file to the project with this function (and the appropriate file h and bridge header too) something does not work.
I see messages in the console:

```
unlink: Operation not permitted
bind: Address already in use
```

Why doesn't this valid C code work in a Swift project — any ideas?

Comment: What are the permissions on the socket file?

Comment: permissions are: srwxr-xr-x, it is in my home directory, I have all the permissions

Comment: Since the unlink fails and the bind fails too, maybe the socket is still in use by a program that's still running, and that makes the code fail with 'Address already in use'?  Find which process could have the socket in use.  If all else fails, try a reboot, but it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Does Apple do any sandboxing that would explain it? Maybe try creating the socket in a location for temporary files instead.

Comment: @Ove location is not important, i did check tmp (and many others) directory too. But sandboxing? Yes, it is good idea, to check.

Comment: @Ove, it was the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It was the problem with sandbox, the valid solution is idea of Ken Thomases in another task, i needed to set two checkboxes (App Sandbox, Network: Incoming Connections (Server) and Outgoing Connections (Client)):

[image: screenshot of settings]

see: [Creating and binding socket on Mac OS Hight Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47117270/creating-and-binding-socket-on-mac-os-hight-sierra)